# How to prevent isolated copper in thermal reliefs / wagon wheels in Altium?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

How to prevent thermal reliefs / wagon wheels messing up copper and creating dead/isolated copper on through holes and VIAs?

[image: 2 row header]

I have a 10pin 2row 1.27mm (50mil) pitch header. This is how Altium connects it to the ground polygon. Same thing happens with VIA stitching.
Is there a better way to do thermal reliefs?

Comment: Check the "Remove Dead Copper"-option in your polygon fill. Although I haven't seen anything looking as bad as your screenshot before, so not posting this as an answer.

Comment: I think you need to change the pad defaults.   Your thermal relief rings have too large a diameter.   Try going into the Board Rules to find that setting.   I dont remember exactly where but it's there.  Post again later if you cant find it and I'll fire up Altium

Comment: You probably get much better results using horizontal/vertical relief traces instead of the 45-degree ones you're using.

Comment: In general, there is no reason to have a thermal relief on vias. To flood your vias: Design  -> Rules -> Plane Connect & Polygon Connect. Enable Advanced and select  Direct Connect for the via connection. While you're at it, clean up the rules for your thru-hole thermal relief, things aren't set up properly in your setup for the pitch/pad size you have (you'll need to specify new rules for that part since the pin spacing is tight).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vias should generally be direct connect (i.e. no thermal reliefs). If you absolutely need thermal reliefs on vias (i.e. if you plan to solder wires to them for test points) then go with horizontal/vertical connects rather than 45 degrees. You can change these settings in the Polygon Properties dialog.

Comment: How about with TH components like in the image? Is modifying the relief settings until the geometry looks acceptable the only way to go?
I'm surprised that such expensive software doesn't handle this well. I would expect that it detected overlapping reliefs of nearby components in the same net and raw a union shape instead of an intersection as in the image in the OP.

Comment: I am actually surprised to see this, as I have not had this issue before. I do know that Altium made some recent changes that affect how polygons are poured, so it's possible it's a new bug. I strongly recommend you post in BugCrunch to report the issue. https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#/bugs/new